# Makefile: Reuse environment variables

Tags: shell, makefile

In my Makefile `deploy` target I create environment variables and I want to reuse those in the following lines:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
deploy:
  export $(shell sh this-script-generate-key-values.sh | xargs)
  echo ${VAR1} #there is no variable here
  echo ${VAR2} #there is no variable here
```

Where:
`this-script-generate-key-values.sh` generates this output:

```
VAR1="somevalue"
VAR2="somevalue"
```

Why the variables are not set in subsequent lines? How can I make it work?

Notes:

- This line works: `sh this-script-generate-key-values.sh | xargs`
- The shell must be `/bin/sh` (no bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `.ONESHELL` special target appears anywhere in the makefile then all recipe lines for each target will be provided to a single invocation of the shell. Newlines between recipe lines will be preserved.

```
.ONESHELL:
deploy:
  export $$(this-script-generate-key-values.sh)
  echo $${VAR1} 
  echo $${VAR2}
```

Comment: This is much better than exporting a script file and executing it separately.

Answer (score 2):

All lines in a Makefile recipe run in a separate shell. You need to run the lines in a single shell. Also you need to escape the dollar sign ($) so that variable substitution is not done by **make** but by the shell.

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
deploy:
  export $$(this-script-generate-key-values.sh | xargs) ;\
  echo $${VAR1} ;\
  echo $${VAR2}
```

Comment: I recommend you do not use make's `shell` function inside a recipe.  It can cause much confusion and you're _already_ in a shell so no need for it.  Replace it with just `export $$(this-script-generate-key-values.sh | xargs); ...`  `make` always run `sh` regardless of your shell.  BTW mrk what is the point of adding in the `| xargs` here?

Comment: @MadScientist of course. Updated the answer.

Comment: @MadScientist `xargs` is not necessary. Thanks for the `$$` tip instead of `shell`.

Comment: @rveerd Thanks. It works, but it's not exactly what I wanted. I just simplify the makefile to make the question simpler. My real makefile has a lot of lines. I didn't want to ;\ in each line. Maybe there is a workaround using eval or similar approach.

Comment: @mrk -- as was mentioned, each recipe line runs in a separate shell, and one shell cannot contaminate the variables of another shell.   So...  given that you don't want to concatenate your recipe lines, you have two choices: either set it in a make variable outside of the recipe (note -- this command would run before any recipe lines were run, so there might be an ordering issue), or you could have the command pipe its output to a temporary file, and read from that file.

Comment: So, what you appear to want is a way to take the output of this script and turn it into **make** variables, not shell variables, so they will be available in all recipes as make variables?  It would be good to be clear about that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on my comment -- you could output to a file, and use the file to generate your output as so:

```
vars.txt:
    this-script-generate-key-values.sh > $@

deploy : vars.txt
    echo VAR1=$$(sed -n 's|VAR1=\(.*\)|\1|p' vars.txt)
    echo VAR2=$$(sed -n 's|VAR2=\(.*\)|\1|p' vars.txt)
```

note: you may have to generate dependencies for vars.txt or declare it .PHONY, otherwise, this will not run on every invocation of make.